# Non-repeatable header in Flutter ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

(Please let me know if this kind of question was already answered somewhere else, as I don't know what in other words to describe this question. Thank you.)

I am designing a Flutter app with a page of showing a list of items, as the screenshot below:

[image: A list of items]

I used `ListView.builder` to iterate a list of items, which can be scrolled down for seeing more items. Now, the header and divider are static on top of the page. However,

**I want the header *Items(16)* and the divider can be scrolled out of page along with the items.**

- Wrapping `ListView` as parent = not ideal (The items scroll was not working);
- Attempt to include header and divider into `ListView.builder` or `ListView.separated` = not suitable.

Is there any way to make it possible? Here is part of my code:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: appBarColor,
        title: Text("Groceries"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // Header //
          Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: "Items",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: " (" + items.length.toString() + ")",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // Divider //
          Divider(
            height: 20.0,
            thickness: 1.0,
          ),

          // Items List //
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    value: true,
                    title: Text(items[index]),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `SingleChildScrollview`

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text("Groceries"),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
    children: [
      // Header //
      Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          text: "Items",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: " (" + '10' + ")",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      // Divider //
      Divider(
        height: 20.0,
        thickness: 1.0,
      ),

      ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 10,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                value: true,
                title: Text("Item $index"),
                onChanged:(value){}
              );
            }),
    ],
  )),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Groceries"),
          ),
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "Items",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: " (" + items.length.toString() + ")",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Divider(
                  height: 20.0,
                  thickness: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                // Todo: Populate the Map data with CheckboxListTile
                // Todo: Make CheckBoxListTile check/uncheck-able
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  onChanged: (changed) {},
                  value: true,
                  title: Text(items[index]),
                );
              },
              childCount: items.length,
            ),
          ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(child :Column(
        children: [
          // Header //
          Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: "Items",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: " (" + items.length.toString() + ")",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // Divider //
          Divider(
            height: 20.0,
            thickness: 1.0,
          ),

          // Items List //
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: neverScrollablePhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    value: true,
                    title: Text(items[index]),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick replies!

From both answers from Tasnuva & Gunaseelan, wrapping with `SingleChildScrollView` does not work, it having error rendering the widgets.

However, from both answers I noticed `scrollDirection: neverScrollablePhysics()` within `ListView.builder`, it does the trick. After I changed the `Column` parent to `ListView` parent, works exactly what I want.

```
body: ListView(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                text: "Items",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: " (" + items.length.toString() + ")",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20.0,
            thickness: 1.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                // Override physics to work with ListView parent
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    value: true,
                    title: Text(items[index]),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Look at my post more clearly, I didn't wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` widget. That's the reason why it will work. try again. Instead of having ListView inside ListView you can have one listview inside column, which is light weight. And give you more performance.

Comment: @Gunaseelan My bad for not noticing that. Tried your solution, it works well. Thank you.